# How not to analyze time based indices in elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-elasticsearch

We are creating time based indices in Elasticsearch. We need to ensure that all string fields are "not analyzed". What are the best practices to achieve this? `**Sample indices are: bounce-email_2017-01-25,  bounce-email_2017-01-26, bounce-email_2017-01-27**`

Answer (score 0):

GET bounce-email_2017-01-25/_mapping

Now over on all fields and verify that they are not analyzed

Comment: Now if I push data for "bounce-email_2017-01-26" index, then will the data be analyzed or not analyzed?

Comment: Its depend on youre mapping, look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html